# Overloading operator "=" for anonymous access types?

Tags: ada

I am working my way through Barnes' excellent Ada book. This is a code sample for deep comparison of linked lists from section 11.7:

```
type Cell is
  record
    Next: access Cell;
    Value: Integer;
  end record;

function "=" (L, R: access Cell) return Boolean is
begin
  if L = null or R = null then    -- universal =
    return L = R;                 -- universal = (Line A)
  elsif L.Value = R.Value then
    return L.Next = R.Next;       -- recurses OK (Line B)
  else
    return False;
  end if;
end "=";
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around why in Line A **operator "=" of the universal_access type** is called (because of the preference rule), on Line B, however, the **user-defined operator "="** is called (which makes recursion possible in the first place), this time with no preference for operator "=" of universal_access.

Both L and R, as well as L.Next and R.Next are of the same anonymous type "access Cell". Why the difference in "dispatching"? Does it have to do with L and R being access parameters? If so, what is the rule there?

I did my best to find anything in the AARM, especially section 4.5.2, but could not make any sense of it.

Cheers.

Comment: it has to do with one or both being `null` in that case

Comment: Thx for the comment. That is what went through my head for a second. However, that would be dynamic dispatch at runtime. To my knowledge, this is only possible with tagged record types, right?

Comment: Either there’s a bug in GNAT (CE 2018) or Barnes is wrong. I see stack overflow from unbounded recursion.

Comment: The place you’re looking for is [ARM 8.6(29.1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-8-6.html#p29.1). Did you know that that version of the LRM is searchable? - which is how I found that para! Looks as tho GNAT has a bug

Comment: Thx, I found that one in my PDF version as well, but did not give it any weight, since I read it as: "regardless of whether you defined an overloaded equality operator, we will use the one for universal_access anyway". I must be misinterpreting?

Comment: Note that this mistake is repeated in section 12.5, in the stacks example, along with a compilation error, for which I posted a [seperate SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59410704/why-is-implicit-conversion-between-anonymous-access-objects-disallowed-in-ada).

Answer (score 5):

I will summarize my findings (with the help of Simon Wright and G_Zeus) as of now. Please correct me if I'm wrong:

According to the standard, `L = null`, `R = null`, `L = R` as well as `L.Next = R.Next` should each unambiguously call the user-defined operator =. `universal_access` operator = must not kick in at all here.

Reason:

The operands `L`, `R`, `L.Next` and `R.Next` violate the precondition in [ARM 4.5.2(9.1-9.4)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-4-5-2.html#p9.1) for interpreting `=` in these expressions as to mean operator = of the `universal_access` type:

The precondition says that neither of the operands are of an access-to-object type (`access Cell`) whose designated type is `Cell` (*check*), `Cell` has a user-defined primitive equality operator (*check*) such that

- its result type is `Boolean` (*check*);
- it is declared immediately within the same declaration list as `Cell` (*check*); and
- at least one of its operands is an access parameter with designated type `Cell` (both operands are, *check*).

The preference rule for operator = of the `universal_access` type in [ARM 8.6(29.1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-8-6.html#p29.1) does not apply here, since it requires "two acceptable interpretations". But because of 4.5.2, operator = of the `universal_access` type is not an acceptable interpretation.

So there is no choice: in all cases (even `L = null`) it has to be the user-defined operator =.

@Simon Wright: So "unbounded recursion" is actually the correct compiler behavior.

@G_Zeus: Issuing an ambiguity error for `l = r` is incorrect compiler behavior, the compiler should have picked `Access_Equal."="`.

The example should correctly read:

```
...

  if Standard."="(L, null) or Standard."="(R, null) then    -- universal =
    return Standard."="(L, R);                              -- universal =
  elsif L.Value = R.Value then
    return L.Next = R.Next;                                 -- recurses OK

...
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation to comment on OP, so I will write an answer instead.

Interestingly enough, I cannot compile such an example (I used Integer access instead, but I doubt it has any relevance) in Gnat 6.1.1. Gnat keeps telling me the use of inline "=" is ambiguous between the overloading "=" and the universal "=" in `Standard`. So I tried:

```
package body Access_Equal is
   function "=" (L,R : access Integer) return Boolean is
   begin
      return Standard."="(L, R) or L.all = R.all;
   end "=";
end Access_Equal;
```

And it seems to do the trick. I cannot use inline "=" in my code however, I have to use fully qualified names:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Access_Equal; use Access_Equal;
procedure Access_Equal_Test is
   l : access Integer := new Integer'(1);
   r : access Integer := new Integer'(1);
begin
   Put_Line(Boolean'Image(Standard."="(l, r))); -- FALSE
   Put_Line(Boolean'Image(Access_Equal."="(l, r))); -- TRUE
   Put_Line(Boolean'Image(l = r)); -- does not work
end Access_Equal_Test;
```

Note: using the `Standard` package *might* be a portability hazard, as it does not seem to be required to define universal "=". More information [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Libraries/Standard).

Comment: FSF GCC 6.1.0, x86_64-apple-darwin15, behaves (for @dacker’s example) like 8.1.0.