# Why is implicit conversion between anonymous access objects disallowed in Ada?

Tags: operator-overloading, ada

I am working my way through Barnes' book 'Programming in Ada 2012'. This is a code sample implementing a stack from section 12.5.

src/stacks.adb: (the main relevant file)

```vhdl
package body Stacks is

   procedure Push(S: in out Stack; X: in Integer) is
   begin
      S := new Cell'(S,X);
   end Push;

   procedure Pop(S: in out Stack; X: in out Integer) is
   begin
      X := S.Value;
      S := Stack(S.Next);
   end Pop;

   function "="(S, T: Stack) return Boolean is
      SS: access Cell := S;
      TT: access Cell := T;
   begin
      while SS /= null and TT /= null loop
         if SS.Value /= TT.Value then
            return false;
         end if;
         SS := SS.Next;
         TT := TT.Next;
      end loop;
      return SS = TT; -- error: implicit conversion of stand-alone anonymous access object not allowed
   end "=";

end Stacks;
```

I have added a comment containing the error that gnat gives me. Why am I not allowed to convert from one anonymous `access Cell` to another?

I can solve the problem by inverting the condition:

```ada
return not (SS /= TT);
```

It mystifies me as John Barnes states earlier that if you define a "=" operator returning a boolean, then the inverse "/=" is generated automatically for you, meaning the opposite.

Similarly, the loop condition can be inverted, in which case it fails to compile with the same message.

Finally, a side-note: the expected behaviour of the program, which it gives after changing to `return not (SS /= TT)` is to recurse infinitely and raise a storage_error due to stack overflow. The reason for that is better seen in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154369/overloading-operator-for-anonymous-access-types/54174833), and is not the subject of this question.

Why is the conversion disallowed by the compiler when I write "="?
Why is it different when I write "/=", which I thought would always be the inverse?

The other files needed in order to compile the example for yourself:

src/stacks.ads:

```ada
package Stacks is

   type Stack is limited private;

   procedure Push(S: in out Stack; X: in Integer);
   procedure Pop(S: in out Stack; X: in out Integer);
   function "="(S, T: Stack) return Boolean;

private

   type Cell is
      record
         Next: access Cell;
         Value: Integer;
      end record;
   type Stack is access all Cell;

end;
```

src/main.adb:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Stacks; use Stacks;

procedure Main is
   A : Stack;
   B : Stack;
begin
   Push(A, 1);
   Push(B, 1);
   Push(A, 2);
   Push(B, 2);
   Push(A, 1);
   Push(B, 1);
   Push(A, 8);
   Push(B, 8);

   declare
      Same : Boolean := A = B;
      Text : String := (if Same then "They are the same" else "They are not the same");
   begin
      Put_Line(Text);
   end;
end Main;
```

stacks.gpr:

```ada
project stacks is
   for Source_Dirs use ("src");
   for Object_Dir use "obj";
   for Main use ("main.adb");
end stacks;
```

Makefile:

```
all:
    gprbuild -d -p -g

clean:
    rm -rf obj *.o *.ali
```

Or compile with gcc:

```
gcc -c src/*.adb
gnatbind main
gnatlink main
```

It gives the same results.

Comment: Rejecting `SS = TT` but accepting `not (SS /= TT)` seems like a compiler bug. I found (GCC9, running under gdb) that the stack overflow happens on `while SS /= null and TT /= null loop`!

Comment: Just for info, using `Standard."="` and `Standard."/="` compiles and works.

Comment: See also [_How can I overload the '=' operator in Ada without creating a recursive function?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6086358/230513)

Comment: Those who use anonymous access types get what they deserve. But you should be aware that anonymous access types don't have "=" defined for them, but may use the operators for universal_access (from Standard). Also, IIRC, anonymous access types may be implicitly converted to named access types with the same designated types. Type Stack is a named access with the same designated type as your anonymous access types, so probably they are being implicitly converted to Stack, which results in a recursive call to the "=" you're defining. That it accepts "/=" but not "=" must be a compiler error.

Comment: I agree that there appears to be a compiler bug for the /= case. The rules are defined in RM 4.5.2(9.1/2 - 9.4/2). My reading of these rules says that /= should not have been allowed. It is correct that = is not allowed, unless using Standard."=" as already suggested. Also relevant reading is AI95-00420-1. Another option that compiles would be to write explicit conversions as in; return Stack (TT) = Stack (SS); This should be legal. Another curious incantation that compiles but shouldn't be legal, I believe, is return not (not (TT = SS));

Comment: @B.Moore Could you explain why adding the double negation is relevant? You say that `SS = TT` should not be legal, so it follows then in the same line that `not (not TT = SS))` should also be illegal, right? Does the compiler offer different opinions of these two expressions that are logically equivalent?

Comment: Yes, the GNAT compiler says that "SS = TT" is illegal, which is correct according to the rules, but it accepts "not (not (SS = TT)), which is logically equivalent, and should also be illegal, but isn't.